# How can I read an user selected file using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to read a XML file as soon as the user selects it from his storage, how can I achieve this? I did read some tutorials but all of them told nothing about reading an user's input file, only reading files that I've created myself with `file.writeAsString` method.

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be to use the package [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) to get a file from your phone's storage then read and parse it with [xml](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) package.

**Example**

```dart
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

_readSelectedFile() async {
   var file = await FilePicker.getFile();
   var xmlString = await file.readAsString();
   var document = xml.parse(xmlString);
}
```